# how can I put write/read protection on the sd card?

Tags: linux

In linux, with Linux built in command, how can I put write/read protection on the sd card ? I will put, with command, protection such as user can not write something on the sd card because I have enabled the only read protection via command.

If you know without command, feel free to share

Answer (score 0):

Anyway with software, you can do only it in a `filesytem` level. If some one format the pendrive, they will get the permission what ever they want to do on it. If there is something at hardware level for making a `sdcard` `readonly`, you will get what you asked here.